# XPATH start scraping after certain word

Tags: xpath

I am trying to get the location  from this html using XPATH. So what I want to say is [in human terms] "when you see **Location:** grab the next piece of text then stop.

```
<td width="670">
        <h1>Accor Vacation Club - SOLD</h1>
        <h2>All Australia, Australia</h2>

        <p class="property_number">Property ref:  002</p>
         
         <h3 class="cl2">Description</h3><p class="xh-highlight">Resort: Accor Vacation Club. <br>Location: Australia. <br>Type of Ownership: Points. <br>Season: All. <br>Size of Unit: Studio. <br>Price: SOLD</p><p class="xh-highlight">&nbsp;</p><p class="xh-highlight"><span style="font-size: 16pt">SOLD</span> </p>         
         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="photorealestate">
         <tbody><tr>
```

I got this far but can't seem to isolate that word:

```
//p[./preceding-sibling::h3[contains(., 'Description')]]
//p/text()[./preceding-sibling::h3[contains(., 'Description')]]
```

Comment: What exactly is "the next piece of text" in your example? Also, can you fix your sample html so tags open and close properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get `"Australia"` as output you can use below expression

```
substring-after(//text()[starts-with(., 'Location')], 'Location: ')
```

This will select text node that starts with word `"Location"` and return sub-string preceded by `"Location: "`